# Should I use mock or sqlite to make some tests od database on node.js app?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, unit-testing

I want to make some test for the database on my nodejs app. I want to know the pros and cons of using mocks or SqLite to test the database.
I found this question:
[Should I use an In-Memory Database instead of mocking out my Repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168108/should-i-use-an-in-memory-database-instead-of-mocking-out-my-repositories)
But it didn't give much information about each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it depends.  If I'm using an ORM I will use SQLite - I assume that the ORM stuff works as expected and it's easier than mocking the ORM.

If I'm writing my own code to do database stuff, I'll mock it.  If I have a database service layer, I'll mock it.

Basically, if I write it I'll mock it and if I use an ORM or library I'll use SQLite.

Comment: I'm  using an ORM [Objection] (http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/) and I take look after `sinon` and it didn't give results such as I want.